# Popover in CollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uipopovercontroller

I am using `UICollectionView`,in this when I click on the cell a popup will come.
In that popup I added a `UITextView` which is created programatically.I gave the frame of that `TextView` is like...

```
  self.myTextView.frame=CGRectMake(50, 62, 200, 321);
```

![enter image description here][1]

when I clicked on the `Textview` the Popup is going like this....

please help....

Comment: It might be because of your keyboard appears

Comment: Did you set auto layout constraints or autoresizing mask in text view and buttons?

Comment: I know that because of the keyboard appears.You know how to solve that

Answer (score 0):

You could use an autoresizing mask for simplicity:

```
self.myTextView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

Comment: You said you created the textview programatically, so this should go right after your `self.myTextView = [[UITextView alloc] init...`